# Why to combine a Raspberry Pi (or similar board computer) and an Arduino for controlling motors?

Tags: arduino, control, motor, raspberry-pi

I am planning to build a omnidirectional holonomic robot, and checking what I should use for the hardware, I saw many people using a Raspberry to compute most stuff, which in turn calls an Arduino to control the motors. But since the Arduino will have to drive some H-bridges, and the board computer is probably a lot more powerful, it seems to me that those drivers for the motors could be controlled by the Raspberry-ish board.

What am I missing?
Why so many people use both at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is Clock on the Raspberry Pi. Note that the raspberry is powerful but not that powerful that it can run an OS and simultaneously give you precisely timed PWM outputs. I assume that you'll be handling the motors with PWM on the Enable pin on the motors.
Reasons:

1. As stated, it is more on getting precise PWM outputs on for the motor driver. The Arduino as a slave controller drive it better.
2. Sure the Raspi is powerful but it is advised to keep the computationally expensive task on the Board and leave everything to the slave controller to ensure an isolation between two.
3. A small reason is also to ensure that running higher voltages(9V,12V) and currents(sometimes >1000 mA) shouldn't damage your more expensive and OS running board.

Have stated the same in my [blog](http://techspirityou.blogspot.com) for my ball tracker.